# Quartus produces different synthesis for same design

Tags: fpga, quartus

I synthesized my design in Quartus for Arria 10 in a remote server. In my memory instantiation, it is saying that it is unable to infer a Block RAM due to asynchronous reads. I tried to synthesize again in my local machine, this time setting a DE1-SoC FPGA as the target device. It properly inferred my memory instantiations as BRAMs. To test my sanity, I decided to bring it to board level in my DE1; the design functioned as expected. I'm just wondering why Quartus produces different synthesis for the same design? Are there some compiler commands that I can use to force Quartus to infer my memory instantiations as BRAM? Thank you.

From the terminal in remote Server:

Quartus Prime Design Software

Version 17.1.1 Build 273 12/19/2017 Patches 1.38 SJ Pro Edition

Comment: How do you know that changing the target device wasn't what fixed it?  Did you try the build on the remote server after you made the change?

Comment: I am using the Pro Edition on the remote server. According to this table, it doesn't support the Cyclone V Product: https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/software/programmable/quartus-prime/download.html. Nonetheless I changed the target to a different device with the same result. Irrespective of the target device, why would one quartus version think my reads are asynchronous while another quartus version doesn't throw an error?

Comment: You could probably do with expanding your question to include the differences between the Quartus that you are using locally and on the server. Inferring what you've said in the comments, on the remote server you have Quartus Pro with an Arria10. Locally you are using Quartus Standard with a CycloneV. Exactly why would you think the results would be the same? I'm not familiar with Pro, but I guess there would be enhanced error or style checking in there. This could be all set in the .qsf which will be different from the one you are using locally.

Comment: Also, check the Arria10 datasheet or Arrria 10 specific IP for the BRAM. It could be that what is an acceptable synthesis template for a Cyclone V is not acceptable for an Arria10 due to the differences in architecture.